# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused |

Tags: laravel, macos, xampp

I'm using MAC OS and I'm new to laravel .. I'm working on laravel using xampp and when i run the command php artisan migrate

I get this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = web and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=web
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I searched and tried most of the ways and it is still not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try the methods below:

> open your .env file and change DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1 to localhost

> try restarting your localhost server (xampp)

> try downgrading your xampp to a lower version